# Фильтрация отношении по максимальному значению laravel 5

Tags: laravel5

Имеются две таблицы

"Games"

[image: Games]

и "game_to_users" в который связаны отношением один ко многим

[image: game_to_users]

**Нужно вывести по одной записи для каждого юзера с максимальным кол-во балов**.

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$games = Games::with(['attempts' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('ball', 'DESC');
    $query->groupBy('user_id');
}])->get();
```

*но оно не работает, выводит записи не с максимальным кол-во баллов, а первые созданные записи. Подскажите пожалуйста как отфильтровать правильно.*

Answer (score 0):

всем спасибо)) это делается так

```
$games = Games::with(['attempts' => function($query){
        $query->where('ball',DB::raw('(select max(ball) from game_to_users as gu2 where gu2.game_id=game_to_users.game_id and game_to_users.user_id=gu2.user_id)'));
        $query->groupBy('user_id');
        $query->orderBy('ball', 'DESC');
    }])->get()
```

;